# Find the Eigenfunctions and Eigenvalues for $u_{xx} + \frac{2}{x}u_x + u_{yy} + \theta u = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

From an old qual exam:

*Find the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues associated with the BVP 
\begin{align}
&u_{xx} + \frac{2}{x}u_x + u_{yy} + \theta u = 0,\quad 0 < x < a, \quad 0 < y < b,\\
&u(x,0) = 0,\quad u(x,b) = 0,\\
&u \text{ bounded as } x \to 0, \quad u_x(a,y) = 0.
\end{align}
($\theta$ a given real number).*

***Hint:*** it may be useful to make the substitution $v = xu$.

My attempt:

Letting $v = xu$ as per the hint, the BVP is transformed into
\begin{align}
&v_{xx} + v_{yy} + \theta v = 0,\quad 0 < x < a, \quad 0 < y < b,\\
&v(x,0) = 0,\quad v(x,b) = 0,\\
&\frac{v}{x} \text{ bounded as } x \to 0, \quad av_x(a,y) = v(a,y).
\end{align}
Solving via separation of variables $v(x,y) = \varphi(x) h(y)$, we get (denoting $\lambda$ the separation constant)
\begin{align}
&h''(y) + (\lambda + \theta)h(y) = 0,\quad h(0) = h(b) = 0\\
&\varphi''(x) - \lambda \varphi(x) = 0, \quad \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} \text{ bounded as } x \to 0, \quad a\varphi'(a) = \varphi(a)
\end{align}
I find the eigenvalues $\lambda_n = \frac{n^2\pi^2}{b^2} - \theta$, and $h_n(y) = \sin(\frac{n\pi y}{b})$. I also find that for $\varphi$,
\begin{align}
\varphi_n(x) = \sinh(\sqrt{\lambda_n}x).
\end{align}
But I can't seem to apply the last homogeneous boundary condition $a\varphi'(a) = \varphi(a)$ at all. It seems like this BC is incompatible with the others - I've made an error somewhere but can't quite pinpoint where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten that $\lambda_n$ isn't an eigenvalue. It's a separation constant, while eigenvalue is $\theta$. Thus your result for $\varphi_n(x)$ is, in expanded view,

$$\varphi_n(x)=\sinh\left(x\sqrt{\frac{n^2\pi^2}{b^2}-\theta}\right).$$

The boundary condition gives you

$$a\sqrt{\lambda_n}\cosh\left(a\sqrt{\lambda_n}\right)=\sinh\left(a\sqrt{\lambda_n}\right).$$

Solving this transcendental equation for $\lambda_n$ (getting $\lambda_{n,m}$ because for each $n$ you'll have a multitude of solutions marked by $m$), you can then find $\theta_{n,m}$ as

$$\theta_{n,m}=\frac{n^2\pi^2}{b^2}-\lambda_{n,m}.$$

Restriction of possible values of $\theta$ is the last action which will finally allow you to satisfy all your boundary conditions.